# SQL Query to retrive matched words

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sentence which is to be searched in DB.I removed stop-words and splitted it into an array of keywords in a variable ie $key[0],$key[1],$key[2].I want to retrieve the data in the order of maximum matched number of keywords , any way for that ? .

please help.

now i am using

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'table' 
WHERE ('colomn' LIKE '%$key1%' 
    AND 'colomn' LIKE '%$key2%'
    AND 'colomn' like '%$key3%'
      );
```

if no result

```
SELECT * 
FROM   'table' 
WHERE ('colomn' LIKE '%$key1%' 
     OR 'colomn' LIKE '%$key2%' 
     OR 'colomn' LIKE '%$key3%'
       );
```

Comment: This is not exact code i just explained my algorithm of working

Comment: look my edited answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL is quite cute on this:

```
SELECT *, (colomn like "%$key1%") + (colomn like "%$key2%") + (colomn like "%$key3%") as match_rate
FROM table
WHERE (colomn like "%$key1%" or colomn like "%$key2%" or colomn like "%$key3%")
ORDER BY match_rate DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

dont use single quotes around table and columns name instead use backticks

like that

```
 Select * from `table` where (`colomn`....
```

instead of

```
 Select * from 'table' where ('colomn'........
```

use second query with OR

i think you look for something like that

```
 order by case 
      when `colomn` LIKE "%$key1%" and `colomn` LIKE "%$key2%" and `colomn` LIKE "%$key3%" then 1 
      when (`colomn` LIKE "%$key1%" and `colomn` LIKE "%$key2%")  or (`colomn` LIKE "%$key1%" and `colomn` LIKE "%$key3%") or (`colomn` LIKE "%$key3%" and `colomn` LIKE "%$key2%") then 2 
    else 3 
 end
```